# Why is the center of $SU(n) ≅ \Bbb Z_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can I show that the center of $SU(n)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_n$?

Comment: I edited your $\LaTeX$. I hope it reflects what you actually meant. Please verify.

Comment: Yes, completely. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Can anyone provide me a reason?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you see why $Z(SU(n))$ contains a copy of $\mathbb Z_n$?

Comment: It is generated by 
C=αIn, where α=exp(2πi/n) is an nth root of unity.

But why?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Are you talking about $\mathbb Z_n$ or $\mathbb Z^n$?

Comment: The first one you mentioned.

Comment: @Jimmy Do you mean why is $C$ in the center, or why doesn't the center contain anything else?

Comment: @ErickWong Haha oops. My bad. My brain turned subscript into superscript.

Comment: Why is the center generated by C?

Comment: Show that the center of $SU(n)$ lies inside the center of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. Then, show the only elements in the center of $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ with determinant $1$ are $n^\text{th}$ roots of unity.